# How to parse json array in postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I need to parse json array from below table column. The result should be answer of Q2 question in below example.

```
id      data
1   [{"questionId":"Q1","answer":"A1"},{"questionId":"Q2","answer":"A2"}]
2   [{"questionId":"Q1","answer":"A1"},{"questionId":"Q2","answer":"A2"}]
```

So the result should be like this

```
1 A2
2 A2
```

I tried with 
  `data::json->'answer' as answer` but doesn't seem to work on array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [the `>#` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

```sql
create temporary table t (id serial primary key, data json);
insert into t (
  data
)
values (
  '[{"questionId":"Q1","answer":"A1"},{"questionId":"Q2","answer":"A2"}]'
);
insert into t (
  data
)
values (
  '[{"questionId":"Q1","answer":"A1"},{"questionId":"Q2","answer":"A2"}]'
);

-- The Q1 ist the 2nd element in the array and has index 1.
select id, data::json#>'{1,answer}' from t;
```

Output:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | ?column?   |
|------+------------|
| 1    | "A2"       |
| 2    | "A2"       |
+------+------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use `json_array_elements` and filter rows using a `WHERE` clause

```
select id, j->>'answer' as answer FROM t 
cross join lateral json_array_elements(data::json) as j
WHERE j->>'questionId' = 'Q2'
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8129e5fcd251b7677576d87873d0a3d5)